# Phone Number Hint API not working on Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

I am using the latest [Phone Number Hint API](https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android) library, provided by Google Play Services, for requesting phone number as hint. Here is my code :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'

private val phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        try {
            val phoneNumber =
                Identity.getSignInClient(requireContext()).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.data)
            Log.d("PhoneNumberRetrieved", phoneNumber)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


private fun requestPhoneNumberHint() {
    val request = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build()
    Identity.getSignInClient(requireContext())
        .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
        .addOnSuccessListener { taskResult ->
            phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(
                IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                    taskResult.intentSender
                ).build()
            )
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            it.printStackTrace()
        }
}
```

Above code is working fine on devices with Android version less than 12. But it is not working properly on devices with Android 12. I have tried on two different devices and here are the results*:

1. Realme narzo 50a** - failureListner is invoked with this message
   **16: API is disabled**
2. Samsung Galaxy M32 - failureListner is invoked with this message
   **16: No phone number is found on this device**. Even though the device has valid numbers available.

* NOTE : The old deprecated [Hint Request API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/HintRequest) is working properly on both devices giving expected results i.e. showing device phone numbers in a pop-up.

** IMPORTANT : Same code worked properly on this device on day 1 of my implementation i.e. it showed the available phone numbers on a bottom sheet. But on the next day, for unknown reasons, it started giving above mentioned result. Although I made no changes in my code.

If anyone else has faced this issue or have any information regarding this, please do share you thoughts.

Comment: @sunny52525 No, I had to resort to old Hint Request API

Comment: Realme narzo 50a** - failureListner is invoked with this message 16: API is disabled 
I think you need to enable phone number sharing from auto fill in settings 

16: No phone number is found on this device. Even though the device has valid numbers available.
I am also facing the same issue. it may be bugs from google side